# Why didn't the United Earth government attack the landed alien ship?

Tags: plot-explanation, independence-day-resurgence

In Independence Day 2: Resurgence:

For 20 years, an alien ship had landed on Earth, in Africa. For at least 10 years, the aliens had routinely skirmished with the local African warlord, General Umbutu, resulting in many human deaths, and a partial learning of the aliens' written language.

1. Why did the United Earth Alliance government not launch a concerted attack and capture the working alien tech at any point between July 5th, 1996, and July 4th, 2016?
2. As the Director of Earth Strategic Defense, Why was it Dr. Levinson's first time to visit the live and functional alien craft?

Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an effort not to undermine the recent unity, and return humanity back to fighting itself, the United Earth Government chose not to invade the territory of the African Warlord who controlled the land beneath and surrounding the landed Alien spaceship.

They wanted to, but other heads prevailed in that arena. Immediately prior to ID:Resurgence, the Warlord dies and his son takes power, and his son immediately invites Dr. Levinson to the ship.

These are explained in the prequel novel, Independence Day: Crucible very clearly, and the book ends with Dr. Levinson flying out to Africa (which is where the movie picks up.)

Comment: It is what I feared! Leftist overreach led to them being criminally ill-prepared for the devastation that followed! I can only imagine ex-President Whitman was greatly against this non-action!

Comment: This is also adressed to some degree in the film itself by Umbutu's son when he first meets Levinson.